# How to obtain access token from Yelp Fusion API using NodeJS

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, yelp

I am trying to obtain the access token for Yelp's API.

Yelp's API documentation:
https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/get_started

I keep running into the error below on my terminal:

```
problem with request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.yelp.com/oauth2/token api.yelp.com/oauth2/token:80
```

Here's my NodeJS code (I took a lot of it from the Node Documentation site):

```
var http = require("http");

var postData = JSON.stringify({
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": "<<client id>>",
        "client_secret": "<<client secret no.>>"
      });

var options = {
  hostname: 'api.yelp.com/oauth2/token',
  port: 80,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
  console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response.');
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

// write data to request body
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Two items that caught my eye:

1. Separate the hostname and the path in your options variable.
2. The YELP Fusion API is HTTPS, not HTTP.  Using HTTP may result in a 302 response (URL Redirection).

   ```
   var https = require('https');

   getYelpAccessCode(function(response) {
       var responseData = JSON.parse(response);
       if (responseData != null) {
           var accessCode = responseData.token_type + " " + responseData.access_token;
       }
   });

   function getYelpAccessCode(callback) {
   const postData = querystring.stringify({
       'client_id': YELP_CLIENT_ID,
       'client_secret': YELP_CLIENT_SECRET
       });

   const options = {
           hostname: 'api.yelp.com',
           path: '/oauth2/token',
           method: 'POST',
           headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
               'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
           }
       };

   const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
           console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
           console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);

           var body = '';

           res.setEncoding('utf8');
           res.on('data', (chunk) => {
               body += chunk;
               console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
           });
           res.on('end', () => {
               console.log('No more data in response.');
               callback(body);
           });
       });

   req.on('error', (e) => {
       console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
   });

   // write data to request body
   req.write(postData);
   req.end();
   }
   ```